# Stop looping on youtube chromeless player

Tags: javascript, youtube, youtube-api, youtube-javascript-api

I am using function below while playing videos on **[my site](http://www.olmasigereken.com/demo3/)**. I want to start videos automatically but when it ends i don't want it to start again. I change as `loop=0` but heaven knows why it didn't work. Am i have to add any additional code?

```
      function ytplayer_render_player( )
  {
    swfobject.embedSWF
    (
      'http://www.youtube.com/apiplayer?video_id='+ ytplayer_playlist[ ytplayer_playitem ].videoid + '&enablejsapi=1&autoplay=1&loop=0&version=3&rel=0&fs=1&playerapiid=ytplayer',
      'ytplayer',
      '400',
      '225',
      '10',
      null,
      null,
      {
        allowScriptAccess: 'always',
        allowFullScreen: 'true'
      },
      {
        id: 'ytplayer'
      }
    );
  }
```

Comment: The default behavior is not to loop, so I don't know why you're seeing that in the first place. I'd have to assume there's some other code being executed here.

Could you put us to a live example that shows off the undesired looping behavior?

Comment: I have added a demo below and also in original post. Autoplay parmeter works by changing but loop isn't.  http://www.olmasigereken.com/demo3/

Answer (score 0):

I took a look at your demo. You have the following code:

```
function ytplayerOnStateChange( state )
{
  if ( state == 0 )
  {
    ytplayer_playitem += 1;
    ytplayer_playitem %= ytplayer_playlist.length;
    ytplayer_playlazy( 100 );
  }
}
```

So whenever playback has ended (state is 0), you initiate playback again. That's why you're seeing the looping; it's coming from your own code, not the API.